# sed pattern to insert a character after first m characters and then after every n characters

Tags: sed

If I have a string and I want to use `sed` such that a colon is inserted after the first 8 characters and then after every 2 characters after it, what would the `sed` pattern look like and what would the replacement pattern look like?

Comment: at least, post the input line and the desired output

Answer (score 1):

awk has `substr()` function, it can solve your problem eaiser:

```
awk -v m="8" -v n="2" 
'{a=substr($0,1,m);
  b=substr($0,m+1);
  gsub(".{"n"}","&:",b)}$0=a":"b'
```

You can change the `m` and `n` to desired value (error handling was not done in my one-liner). If we do a test:

```
$ awk -v m="8" -v n="2" '{a=substr($0,1,m);b=substr($0,m+1);gsub(".{"n"}","&:",b)}$0=a":"b'<<<"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
aaaaaaaa:aa:aa:aa:a
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/../&:/4g' file
```

Insert a `:` after the 4th occurrence of 2 characters and then globally throughout the line.